# Check input radio on image click

Tags: jquery, html, image, radio-button

Here's my HTML:

```
<img src="img.jpg" class="img-ms-form">
<div class="radio">
    <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="optradio-1" required>Option 1</label>
</div>
```

I'm trying to check the radio button if the image is clicked. Here's what I've tried:

```
$('.img-ms-form').click(function(){
    $(this).next('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at my approach as well. Not asking to accept but not using JavaScript much is better. `:D`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.next()` and `.find()` as shown :-

```
$('.img-ms-form').click(function(){
  $(this).next('div.radio').find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('.img-ms-form').click(function() {
  $(this).next().find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="img.jpg" class="img-ms-form">
<div class="radio">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio-1" required>Option 1</label>
</div>
I'm trying to check the radio button if the image is clicked. Here's what I've tried:
```

1. Radio is not sibling so you cant just use `.next('input[type=radio]')`
2. Use `.next()` with `.find()`

Comment: @onerkript happy coding mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I am very late. Just to do it using **Pure HTML**, you can use this:

```html
<label for="optradio-1"><img src="img.jpg" class="img-ms-form" /></label>
<div class="radio">
  <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="optradio-1" id="optradio-1" required>Option 1</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice approach indeed but this messes up my css. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @onerkript Sure... :D